# How to generate unaligned subplots using tiledlayout?

Tags: matlab, subplot

I plan to generate a plot that has 3 subplots on the first row, 4 subplots on the second row using `tiledlayout`. As 4 is not a multiple of 3, I have difficulties to correctly manage it. All examples I have seen are aligned subplots (tiles) though.

Normally I will do that with something like:

```
subplot(2,3,1); plot(...);
subplot(2,3,2); plot(...);
subplot(2,3,3); plot(...);
subplot(2,4,5); plot(...);
subplot(2,4,6); plot(...);
subplot(2,4,7); plot(...);
```

Is it possible to achieve this goal by using `tiledlayout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method 1: Continuing to Use `subplot()`

If you wish to continue using the `subplot()` function you can use the Lowest-Common-Multiple (LCM) of 3 and 4 in this case. In this case using a subplot grid that has 2 rows and 12 columns will suffice. The key to this method is to have the subplots span multiple **positions**. The 3rd argument in the `subplot()` function will dictate the positions that each subplot will span over from start to end. I find that the subplot and span concept carries over to many languages which is a reason why I tend to use it over `tiledlayout()`.

[image: Subplot Positions]

[image: Subplots Graphs 1]

```
clf;
subplot(2,12,1:4); plot(rand(5,1));
subplot(2,12,5:8); plot(rand(5,1));
subplot(2,12,9:12); plot(rand(5,1));
subplot(2,12,13:15); plot(rand(5,1));
subplot(2,12,16:18); plot(rand(5,1));
subplot(2,12,19:21); plot(rand(5,1));
subplot(2,12,22:24); plot(rand(5,1));
```

[image: Subplot Graphs 2]

```
clf;
subplot(2,12,2:4); plot(rand(5,1));
subplot(2,12,5:7); plot(rand(5,1));
subplot(2,12,8:10); plot(rand(5,1));
subplot(2,12,13:15); plot(rand(5,1));
subplot(2,12,16:18); plot(rand(5,1));
subplot(2,12,19:21); plot(rand(5,1));
subplot(2,12,22:24); plot(rand(5,1));
```

---

### Method 2: Using `tiledlayout()`

```
Grid_Height = 2; Grid_Width = 12;
tiledlayout(Grid_Height,Grid_Width);

Position = 1; Height = 1; Width = 4;
nexttile(Position,[Height,Width]);
plot(rand(5,1));

Position = 5; Height = 1; Width = 4;
nexttile(Position,[Height,Width]);
plot(rand(5,1));

Position = 9; Height = 1; Width = 4;
nexttile(Position,[Height,Width]);
plot(rand(5,1));

Position = 13; Height = 1; Width = 3;
nexttile(Position,[Height,Width]);
plot(rand(5,1));

Position = 16; Height = 1; Width = 3;
nexttile(Position,[Height,Width]);
plot(rand(5,1));

Position = 19; Height = 1; Width = 3;
nexttile(Position,[Height,Width]);
plot(rand(5,1));

Position = 22; Height = 1; Width = 3;
nexttile(Position,[Height,Width]);
plot(rand(5,1));
```