# Center alignment for tiledlayout

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to align all the tiles in the `tiledlayout` to the center, such as the illustration below?

[image]

Comment: With the old `subplots()` this used to be possible. There you'd use 3 rows, 60 columns and set the first row to cover columns 1-2, 3-4, and 5-6; the 2nd and 3rd rows to cover columns 2-3 and 4-5. How is this different from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69804596/5211833) you accepted? That seems to have exactly what you want.

Comment: @Adriaan In my case I would like to stick to use `tiledlayout`, because of its flexibility to adjust the margins and gaps between tiles.

Comment: The second part of the answer you accepted earlier seems to do just that, with `tiledLayout`. Can you please [edit] the question to add a [mcve] and clarify why that answer doesn't work for your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = -2*pi:0.1:2*pi;
y = sin(x);
t = tiledlayout(3,6);
nexttile([1,2])
plot(x,y)
nexttile([1,2])
plot(x,y)
nexttile([1,2])
plot(x,y)
nexttile([1,1])
axis off
nexttile([1,2])
plot(x,y)
nexttile([1,2])
plot(x,y)
nexttile([1,1])
axis off
nexttile([1,1])
axis off
nexttile([1,2])
plot(x,y)
nexttile([1,2])
plot(x,y)
nexttile([1,1])
axis off
xlabel(t,'xlabel')
ylabel(t,'ylabel')
```